# Introducing a new variable in implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

This may seem kinda stupid, but what I have is: 
$\frac xy + \frac yx = a$ (a is a constant) 
this is a simple implicit differentiation that I can solve, however what I'm trying to do is introducing a new variable z for example, and letting it equal to x/y
so it becomes: 
 $z + \frac1z = a$ 
and then differentiating in terms of $Z$ in order to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, however I'm not sure if I can do that and if that will give me $\frac{dy}{dx}$, I would appreciate it if someone can give me a hint, thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how this introduction of $z$ should lead to $y'$ and why you would want to do that esp. if direct differentiation works.

Comment: @KurtG. It's due to curiosity, nothing more, thanks btw!

Comment: I think that (as always when doing this sort of thing) you need to take care about what is a function of what. Here you really have $z(x,y(x))=x/y(x)$, so if you differentiate the $z+1/z=1$ you'll get $1-(1/z^2)\frac{dz}{dx}$ and we can calculate $\frac{dz}{dx}=1/y(x)-(x/y(x)^2)\frac{dy}{dx}$ and eventually extract $\frac{dy}{dx}$.